# how widget can replace parent select in jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, inheritance, widget

I make plugin:

```
$.widget("my.idautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

    options: {
        oldselect:{},
        id:""
    },
    _create: function () {
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this);

        this.options.oldselect=this.options.select;
        this.options.select=this.sel;
    },

    sel:function (event, ui) {
        console.log("Autocomplete sel " + $(this).attr("id"));
    }
}
```

later I try use this select as:

```
$("input").idautocomplete({select:function(){alert(1);} });
```

Then replace this select I can't see messages ...log("Autocomplete sel... My function "sel" not work after this.
How can i write my select what uset in plugin and not crash then it replaced by external code?

in code:

```
    $.widget("my.idautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

    options: {
        id:""
    },

    select:function (event, ui) {
        console.log("Autocomplete sel " + $(this).attr("id"));
    }
}
```

"select" is not work then selecting element in dropdown

Comment: I hope you noticed that you used `sel` and `select`

Comment: Then I select item in dropdown, automatically called select(sel) and executed my code where I save ID in control and get it later from external code.

Comment: `$("input").idautocomplete({sel:function(){alert(1);} });` try this

Comment: No! I need call $("input").idautocomplete({select:function extern_f(){alert(1);} }); And then code call "extern_f" AND "sel" Not only "extern_f" and not only "sel". And called "select" from source autocomplete by selecting from dropdown. I need exec "sel" and want not loose "extern_f"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.widget("my.idautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

    options: {
           oldselect:undefined,
           select:function sel_(event, ui) {
                    var th=this;
                     //some my plugin code
                     ...
                      // call select added from HTML programmer
                    $(th).idautocomplete("sel",event, ui);
            }
    },
    sel:function oldSel(event, ui) {
       var th=this;

        // if has external added select, call it
       var oldSelect = th.options.oldselect;
        if(oldSelect!==undefined){
            oldSelect.call(th,event, ui);
        }
    },

    _setOption: function () {
        if (arguments[0]=="select") {
           //getting a new onSelect function and save it in options
            this.options.oldselect=arguments[1];
             //save private plugin select
            var tst=this.options.select;
             // call _setOption to correct initialisation autocomplete
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
             // restore private select as default
            this.options.select=tst;
        }else{
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },

.....

})(jQuery, window, document);
```